# Set console buffer size or change window size

Tags: c#, linux, console, .net-core

I'm making a console application (targeted at linux) in which i need to both, change the buffer size and resize the window, but both of them throw PlatformNotSupportedException.

What are the alternatives to make it work on linux? I prefer not to use PInvoke but if nothing else works I wouldn't mind.

EDIT:

As requested here is the atempted code.

```
Console.SetBufferSize(a, b);
```

throws

```
PlatformNotSupportedException
```

Comment: You should post your already attempted code, so people have a better idea of what to recommend :)

Comment: how is this c# tag?

Comment: I guess it's .NET Core, some code sample could help

Comment: I dont know, maybe because it's in c#, and im asking about a solution IN C#?

Comment: Hmmm.... It's documented to work on both Core 2.0 and 2.1:

Comment: Actually its not, go look at source.dot.net in ConsolePal.Unix they just throw PnsException

Comment: I am going to suggest that this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to resize the console window from your program. You can do it (via PInvoke), but the convention is that the user sets the size to what they want. Consider that they may be remotely using the program over an ssh connection.

Comment: In this case it's the programs desired functionality to manipulate the window & buffer size

Comment: I'm not doubting that the source shows that exception being thrown (it's showing up, after all), but the document that my comment originally pointed (it seems to have disappeared) was for Console.SetBufferSize on .NET Core 2.0 (it even has sample code): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setbuffersize?view=netcore-2.0

Comment: @Flydog57 Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't cover platforms. Lots of functionality like this is present in multiple versions of .NET Core, but only works on some platforms.